# Webview webcontent not loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load some HTML content (it is a hyperlink) in WebView. But when I click that link nothing is opening. But the same link is working in browser or iOS WebView perfectly.

The code I try:

```
htmlContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        htmlContent.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

htmlContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Html.fromHtml(categoryItemsBean.getContent()).toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Value of `categoryItemsBean.getContent()`.

> `<p><a title="كتاب مساعدة الأصدقاء"
>   href="https://www.manhal.com/platform/stories/demo/index.php?storyid=31"
>   target="_blank">كتاب مساعدة الأصدقاء&nbsp;</a></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Using loadData() method for loading html content on webview

Sample

```
String unencodedHtml ="&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;'%23' is the percent code for ‘#‘ &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";

String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes(),Base64.NO_PADDING);

htmlContent.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Convert your html content into base64